# How to write unit tests for a post install script?

Tags: unit-test, postinstall

I'm trying to write a unit test for a post install script class, a class that implements InstallHandler interface.
I'm testing two cases:
1- No previous version is defined, for that I just use this:

```
PostInstallClass postinstall = new PostInstallClass();
Test.testInstall(postinstall, null);
```

This is working fine.

2- A previous version exists, but for that I'm getting an error System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject

```
PostInstallClass postinstall = new PostInstallClass();
Test.testInstall(postinstall,  new Version(1, 0));
```

So how to test this second case? How to simulate a test environment where a previous version of a managed package exists?
Thanks.

Comment: Where is the System.QueryException happening? Your current description does not show that.

Comment: You probably assign the result of a query directly to an instance of an SObject. In general, it'd be a better idea to assign it to a `List<SObject>` and then handle the 0-results case appropriately.

Answer (score 5):

The System.QueryException happened in Test.testIntall(postInstall, new Version(1, 0)). But I figured out the problem. I need to put Test.testInstall(postinstall, null) before the other one. So this way it works fine:

```
PostInstallClass postinstall = new PostInstallClass();
Test.testInstall(postinstall,  null);
Test.testInstall(postinstall,  new Version(1, 0));
```

This way, the system fiends something (the provisos version) and thus there is no error anymore.

Thanks anyway!

Comment: That is an interesting catch!